# Append names to a list of chunks using apply function

Tags: r

I have split a huge list of genes (57539) into 30 chunks based on the number of cores available on the server in R.

```
ncores=30
L <- length(gene.data$geneId)
list.of.chunks  <-  split(seq_len(L), sort(rep_len(seq_len(ncores), L)))
```

**Here what my list.of.chunks looks like:**

[image]

**Here what my gene.data looks like:**

[image]

Now I want to append geneIds from the gene.data into the list.of.chunks. I have used **apply** function to append names.

```
gene.chunks = tapply(as.factor(gene.bed$geneId), list.of.chunks)
```

*But i am getteing this error:*

Error in tapply(as.factor(gene.bed$geneId), list.of.chunks) :
arguments must have same length

**1-** Can anyone give a hint on how i can solve this error?

**2-** Are there any other functions that i can use?

**Below is an example of what I want**

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: For tapply you need two vectors of same length and a function. One vector are some data and second vector assigns elements of the first one into a group. The function is applied on all data from one group. Most common example is to calculate mean for each group. It is not clear what is your list.of.chunks which has to be the same length as gene ids.

Comment: Hey @Ivana I add some extra info related to the inputs structure. Hope now everything gets a little bit clear so you can help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace row indices in `list.of.chunks` with `geneId`

```
gene.chunks<-lapply(list.of.chunks, function(x) {
gene.data$geneId[x] #gene.data[x,] for all column
})
```